# Implementing Protocol In Generic class in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift2

Let say I want to make Class `TableViewDataSourceImpl` like this :

```
class TableViewDataSourceImpl<T, U: UITableViewCell where U: ReusableCell>:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     }
}
```

then xcode show me error `type 'TableViewDataSource<T,U>' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'`

is this a bug in xcode? or swift cannot make class with generic that implement protocol? because I gonna make `tableView.datasource = tableViewDataSource`

i know that we cant convert our swift generic into objective-c, but I not gonna use any objective-c here

I do this in xcode 7 beta 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update my xcode to beta 2 and it works!